# how to create password protected web pages in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, .htaccess, jsp, servlets

I am developing a website using jsp-servlet in google app engine. I want to secure some web pages from all the users that visit my site. So is there any way to password protect my web pages. I know it is easily done by htaccess in apache. Can htaccess work in google app engine? if Yes, please specify the process.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml#Required_Login_or_Administrator_Status

Comment: who are thinking that this is not a useful question. Please give me the resion. This is a link to password protected the web pages in apache http://viralpatel.net/blogs/password-protect-your-webpages-using-htaccess/ so please tell me there is any way to create password protected pages in google app engine like above.Than vote against my question

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the [App Engine Users API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/overview). This allows users to log in to your app using their Google account. If you want to control who can get into what parts of your app, you could check the logged-in user's ID against a list of allowed users in your data store when they make a request to your servlet.

**Edit:**
You're not going to find a method exactly like using `.htaccess` files -- that's just not how App Engine works. You have code in your servlets that are responsible for rendering pages. In this code, you'll need to add a check to see if the user has access, but only for the pages that you'd like to check.

Here's a code sample, which I hope might clarify things. This is a slightly-modified version of the code at the link I sent you.

```
public class MySecretServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
        resp.setContentType("text/html");

        if (req.getPathInfo().equals("/secret_page") {
            if (req.getUserPrincipal() != null && 
                req.getUserPrincipal().getUserId().equals("admin-id")) {
                // render your protected page here
            } else {
                resp.getWriter().println("<p>Please <a href=\"" +
                                         userService.createLoginURL(thisURL) +
                                         "\">sign in</a>.</p>");
            }
        } else {
            // render your unprotected content here
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the security constraint features in your `web.xml` file. [You can find the documentation for those here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Security_and_Authentication). This is less flexible, though, as you can only change access rights between "everyone" and "admin-only".

Comment: it is a public website, any one can access it. I want to protect some pages(because they are only used by admin), so i need a solution. It is easily done by htaccess in apache. By htaccess u can password protected your web pages not complete site.

Comment: When you write your servlet, you get to write the code that controls the logic behind it. That means that you can insert the logic to check for logged in users at any point. You don't have to protect your whole site.

Comment: sir please see the following web page specially manual way http://viralpatel.net/blogs/password-protect-your-webpages-using-htaccess/ it is for apache. I want this type of password protected page in Google app engine. So please give me the solution.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer Will Brown.But i want the functionality like htaccess because by htaccess  we can protect one web page or more than one page. It give another additional functionality that access protect web pages by many users that are specifed in htpassswrd file. But if i am using your answer(servlet) so it is work only for single web page and single user. But thankyou for your    answer. i am still searching & there is a file in google api called yaml i think it is solution for above problem.

Comment: one stupid people thinks that it is not a useful question & not show any research effort.

Comment: As I said above, you aren't going to find something like `.htaccess` for App Engine. The closest you'll find is `app.yaml`, which presveva mentioned in their comment, or `web.xml` for Java, which is what I mentioned in my answer. Both of these have the same capabilities.

Comment: ok will Brown thankyou, ya i know both are same. so finally there is no exact solution for that problem so i am using alternative solution(web.xml or app.yaml) and please give the vote for this question because it is useful one and i am accepting your answer. Thankyou